# Taking derivative of complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

I've came across something in a textbook on wave propagation and it goes as follows.

$$\frac{d}{dx_3}\bigg(| R|^2+|T|^2\bigg)$$ where both $ R$ and $  T$ depend on $x_3$.

Both quantities contain real and imaginary parts, and the result they give is

$$\frac{d}{dx_3}\bigg(| R|^2+| T|^2\bigg) = \frac{d  R}{dx_3}\bar R + R\frac{d\bar R}{dx_3}+\frac{d\bar T}{dx_3}T+\bar T\frac{dT}{dx_3}$$

where I assume the bar indicates complex conjugates. I've never seen this before. Could someone explain if this correct, how this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complex number $z$ we have $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$. Then your function reads

$$|R|^2+|T|^2=R\overline{R}+T\overline{T}.$$

Differentiation with respect to $x_3$ is now an application of the product rule (and sum rule).